# Graham's number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In order to understand how big Graham's number really is, I tried to come up with the largest number I could understand and then I tried to compare it with Graham's number. Coming up with the number was not the hard part, but comparing it with Graham's number turned out to be really hard.

So the number is the following, imagine 'the largest number with a name' googolplexian, or 10 to the power of googolplex or with Knuth's notation $(10↑^2 4)↑2$. Imagine the number 10 to the power of googolplexian to the power of googolplexian to the power of googolplexian etcetera, repeat this  for 10 to the power of googolplexian to the power of googolplexian to the power of googolplexian etc times, repeat this again for t10 to the power of googolplexian to the power of googolplexian etcetera times. Then again repeat and repeat this again, well you get the idea.

You could think of it as 'levels' so the first level would be the 10 to the power of googolplexian to the power of googolplexian etcetera times would be the first level (I believe by Knuth's notation this level would be the second arrow). Letting the amount of googolplexian times you take a power of a power decides would then be the second level (this then should the third arrow in Knuth's notation). Let there be, you already guessed it, a googolplexian levels, which in Knuth's notation then would be $10↑^{googolpexian}googolplexian$. So $10↑↑...↑googolplexian$ with a googolpexian arrows. How would this rank with the G's used for Grahams number?

It is clear that this number of $10↑^{googolplexian}googolpexian$ is bigger than the G1 of of Graham's number which is $3↑^43$ or 3↑↑↑↑3. However, would this number also be larger than G2 which is $3↑^{G_1}3$?

Of course the number G1 is larger than the number googolplexian, however does this outweigh the fact the the number googolplexian is the number behind the arrow rather than the number 3 in Graham's number (since this number has an exponentially increasing effect in this case).

**So in short, using Knuth's notation, where would the number $10↑^{googolplexian}googolpexian$ rank relative to the G's used for Graham's number.**

Comment: Funny when you think that even a googol is impossible to grasp.

Comment: I don't think your notation for "googolplexian" is right. By your prose description it should be $$10^{10^{10^{10^2}}},$$ but your notation unfolds to $$ 10^{2\cdot 10^{10^{10}}} $$ which is much smaller. It doesn't look like googolplex or $10^{\it googolplex}$ have nice uparrow notations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ denote the googolplexian.

Then the quantity $10 \uparrow^N N$ satisfies
\begin{align}
   10 \uparrow^N N &< 10 \uparrow^N (10 \uparrow^N 10) = 10 \uparrow^{N+1} 10 \\
   &< (3 \uparrow^{N+1} 3) \uparrow^{N+1} (3 \uparrow^{N+1} 3) \\
   &< 3 \uparrow^{N+1} (3 \uparrow^{N+1} (3 \uparrow^{N+1} 3)) = 3 \uparrow^{N+2} 4 \\
   &< 3 \uparrow^{N+2} (3 \uparrow^{N+2} 3) = 3\uparrow^{N+3} 3.
\end{align}
(Here, the only step where we are not simply increasing one argument or another is the one from the second line to the third, where I say that the expression $3\uparrow^k 3 \uparrow^k 3 \uparrow^k 3$ is maximized when calculated from right to left: the way that $3\uparrow^{k+1}4$ is defined.)

But also, $10 \uparrow^N N > 3 \uparrow^N 3$.

In general, the expression $a \uparrow^k b$ is mostly determined by the value of $k$: so long as $a$ and $b$ are not insanely huge numbers that themselves require $\uparrow^k$ to represent, we have $a \uparrow^k b < 3 \uparrow^{k+3} 3$ or so. (And the inequalities above are sloppy; if we're careful, we can probably show $10\uparrow^N N < 3\uparrow^{N+1}3$.)

So essentially, since $N$ is somewhere between $4$ and $G_1$ (but very far from both extremes), $10 \uparrow^N N$ is somewhere between $G_1 = 3\uparrow^4 3$ and $G_2 = 3\uparrow^{G_1} 3$ (but very far from both extremes).